# Is making name column PK is bad practice rather than ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently was asked to checkout a database structure and suggest changes that might describe database more professionally. I was going through tables script and came across with a table which developer created but in very strange way (at least to me). He didn't create any ID column to uniquely identify the record, instead he made the `name` column the PK and referred to it in child tables which was pretty strange to me as I never used this practice ever before.

Here is the structure of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE  egc_manufacturer 
(
     manufacturer_part_number varchar(500) not null,
     manufacturer_number varchar(500) not null,
     manufacturer_name varchar(500) default null,
     supplier_contact varchar(200) default null,
     supplier varchar(50) default null,
     insertion_timestamp timestamp(0) default current_timestamp,
     cmrt_supplier_contact varchar(200) default null,

     primary key (manufacturer_part_number, manufacturer_number)
);
```

I was emphasising on adding a column `ManufacturerID` and make it the primary key and use it as foreign key in child tables because this seems to be the more professional approach to me.

I was just wondering if what I am suggesting is really going to make some impact on design even if does not increase the performance or not? Should I ask them to change the table design or let it be? Hope someone can explain.

Comment: If `(manufacturer_part_number, manufacturer_number)` make a perfectly fine natural primary key, there's nothing wrong with that. Please define "more professional"…

Comment: I too don't see a problem with that. The only thing you should pay attention is the length of those columns: an index entry has a limitation on the total length of the data it can store. I would be defensive here and reduce both columns to maybe only 100 characters  - just to be on the safe side

Comment: @deceze So `(manufacturer_part_number, manufacturer_number)` if used as foreign key in another table will not affect the performance in any sort of way ?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a many to many relationship between manufacturers and part numbers. So, this looks like a join table to me, and it solves the problem of multiple manufacturers having the same part number(s). The manufacturer_number is the manufacturerID in a sense. I would expect manufacturer_number to be the PK in another table tracking more detailed info per manufacturer.

So long story short, I don't see a problem if what I described above is in fact the purpose of this table.

Comment: you're right there is many to many relationship between these tables, so again as I mentioned above in comment `(manufacturer_part_number, manufacturer_number)` behaving as reference key in child table will not be a problem at all ? I can say the design of the table is perfect ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. I would not flag it as a problem. My suggestion for improving your database is to review the indexes. A poorly indexed DB can lead to poor performance.

Answer (score 2):

Using a string -- such as a name -- as a primary key is generally not considered a best practice.  However, I'm a little confused by the question, because there is nothing called `name` in the table and the primary key is a composite primary key.

Here are some reasons why names and the like are not preferred:

- Indexes are a wee bit more efficient if the keys are of fixed size and relatively smaller.  A win for integers over strings.
- Names and external ids can change over time.  Not good for a primary key.
- Foreign key references need to include all components of a primary key -- up to about 1,000 extra characters in this case.
- The types need to exactly match for foreign key references.  Hopefully, you are not dealing with multiple collations!